# java 8 creating custom object from a list of objects

Tags: java-8

This is extension to question .I have a list of messages .I want to create a list of custom message with their audit  values.

[list of id from a list of age using java 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43920835/list-of-id-from-a-list-of-age-using-java-8)

```
public class Messages {

int id;
String message;
int audId;
String audmessage;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public int getAudId() {
    return audId;
}

public void setAudId(int audId) {
    this.audId = audId;
}

public String getAudmessage() {
    return audmessage;
}

public void setAudmessage(String audmessage) {
    this.audmessage = audmessage;
}

public Messages(int id, String message, int audId, String audmessage) {

    this.id = id;
    this.message = message;
    this.audId = audId;
    this.audmessage = audmessage;
  }
}


public class CustomMessage {

int id;
String msg;
List<Aud> list;
//getters and setters
 }

public class Aud {

int id;
int message;
   //getters and setters
 }


  public class Demo {

    public static  void main(String args[]){
      List<Messages> list = new ArrayList<Messages>();
      list.add(new Messages(1,"abc",10,"a1"));
      list.add(new Messages(2,"ac",21,"a2"));
      list.add(new Messages(3,"adc",31,"a3"));
      list.add(new Messages(4,"aec",40,"a4"));
      list.add(new Messages(1,"abc",11,"a5"));
      list.add(new Messages(2,"ac",22,"a5"));
     }
```

Expected output is 1,abc->List of audits as (10,a1),(11,a5);

Comment: btw you *should* really stop posting questions  like how this is done; you must provide at least *some effort*...

Answer (score 2):

The answer here (if I understood correctly) is almost the same as in the previous question, with a couple of assumptions. First is that your `Aud` constructor is actually present and looks like this:

```
    public Aud(int id, String message) {
        this.id = id;
        this.message = message;
    }
```

And than you *do not have* a `Holder` for `id and message`, so I've used `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` instead.

```
 Map<SimpleEntry<Integer, String>, List<Aud>> map = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                 m -> new SimpleEntry<>(m.getId(), m.getMessage()),
                 Collectors.mapping(
                       m -> new Aud(m.getAudId(), m.getAudMessage()), 
                       Collectors.toList())));
```

**EDIT**

```
List<CustomMessage> l = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> new SimpleEntry<>(m.getId(), m.getMessage()),
                    Collectors.mapping(m -> new Aud(m.getAudId(), m.getAudMessage()), Collectors.toList())))
            .entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(e -> new CustomMessage(e.getKey().getKey(), e.getKey().getValue(), e.getValue()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I have no idea what `want to check for null using optional` is supposed to mean.

If you are using setters and getters you can replace this:

```
 m -> new Aud(m.getAudId(), m.getAudMessage())
```

with :

```
m -> {
    Aud aud = new Aud(); 
    aud.setId(m.getAudId()); 
    aud.setMessage(m.getAudMessage());
    return aud;
}
```

Comment: Just want to mention  i dont want to use constructor .want to use getter and setters.there is reason to it.custommessage is holder for id and mesage which has list of Aud

Comment: Just to update i want a list of CustomMessage as my result ie message with list of audit

Comment: @coder25 so you *actually* want to return a list of `CustomMessage` right?

Comment: Yes and also want tocheck for null using optional.originally custom message has many fields not just this two

Comment: @coder25 see EDIT. Also you can't add some many details and expect us to just answer them.

Comment: Ok but can u explain the y we used simpleentry ?.I mean we have custommessage where detail of audit and message must go so if i have 5 fields in messages along with list of audits you have created an entry set so we will add all parameters there in comma separated e.getValue

Comment: I have posted a separate question where i have tried certain approaches.Please have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43938467/java-8-use-reduce-and-collectors-grouping-by-to-get-list