# java 8 use reduce and Collectors grouping by to get list

Tags: java-8, java-stream

**EDIT**
**Request to provide answer to First approach also using reduce method **

```
 public class Messages {
  int id;
  String message;
  String field1;
  String field2;
  String field3;
  int audId;
  String audmessage;
 //constructor
   //getter or setters
 }


public class CustomMessage {

 int id;
 String msg;
 String field1;
 String field2;
 String field3;
 List<Aud> list;
 //getters and setters
}


  public class Aud {

    int id;
    String message;
   //getters and setters
   }


   public class Demo {

    public static  void main(String args[]){
      List<Messages> list = new ArrayList<Messages>();
      list.add(new Messages(1,"abc","c","d","f",10,"a1"));
      list.add(new Messages(2,"ac","d","d","f",21,"a2"));
      list.add(new Messages(3,"adc","s","d","f",31,"a3"));
      list.add(new Messages(4,"aec","g","d","f",40,"a4"));
      list.add(new Messages(1,"abc","c","d","f",11,"a5"));
      list.add(new Messages(2,"ac","d","d","f",22,"a5"));
     }
```

I want the message to be mapped with audits 
CustomMessage must have ->1,"abc","c","d","f"----->List of 2 audits (10,a1) and (11,"a5");

There are two ways to do it

**1.Reduce-I would like to use reduce also to create my own accumulator and combiner**

```
   List<CustomMessage> list1= list.stream().reduce(new ArrayList<CustomMessage>(),
            accumulator1,
            combiner1);

    **I am unable to write a accumulator and combiner**
```

**2.Collectors.groupingBy-**

- I do not want to use constructors for creating the **Message** and
     neither for **Custom Message**.here I    have less fields my actual object has many fields.Any way to have a static 
     method for object creation
- Is there is a way to do it via reduce by writing accumulator or
     combiner

  ```
        List<CustomMessage> l = list.stream()
          .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> new SimpleEntry<>(m.getId(), m.getMessage()),
                  Collectors.mapping(m -> new Aud(m.getAudId(), m.getAudMessage()), Collectors.toList())))
          .entrySet()
          .stream()
          .map(e -> new CustomMessage(e.getKey().getKey(), e.getKey().getValue(), e.getValue()))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
  ```

Can anyone help me with both the approaches.

Comment: what should happen if you have a Messages like this `new Messages(1,"abc","d","c","f",10,"a1"));` together with the messages you have

Comment: this case will not happen in my scenerio

Comment: For the `groupingBy()` approach, does your `Message` class define `equals()` (and `hashcode()`)?

Comment: I assume `message` in `Aud` is a `String` ?

Comment: @OleV.V. yes it has equals and hashcode .It is on id field

Comment: So the instance variable `message` in `Aud` should be a `String` so it can hold `"a1"` or `"a5"`?

Comment: Yes i have updated it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will create a `Collection` of `CustomMessage`. I would recommend putting a constructor in `CustomMessage` that takes a `Messages` argument. And maybe also move the mergeFunction out of the `collect`.

```
Collection<CustomMessage> customMessages = list.stream()
        .collect(toMap(
                Messages::getId,
                m -> new CustomMessage(m.getId(), m.getMessage(), m.getField1(), m.getField2(), m.getField3(),
                        new ArrayList<>(singletonList(new Aud(m.getAudId(), m.getAudmessage())))),
                (m1, m2) -> {
                    m1.getList().addAll(m2.getList());
                    return m1;
                }))
        .values();
```

What [toMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toMap-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.Function-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) does here is : The first time a `Messages` `id` is encountered, it will put it to a Map as key with value the newly created `CustomMessage` by the second argument to `toMap` (the *"valueMapper"*). The next times it will merge two `CustomMessage` with the 3rd argument the *"mergeFunction"* that will effectively concatenate the 2 lists of `Aud`.

And if you absolutely need a `List` and not a `Collection`:

```
List<CustomMessage> lm = new ArrayList<>(customMessages);
```

Comment: i think i updated my question when u answered.can you please check my updated question

Comment: Nice. We’re giving the asker something to choose from. And congrats on the 10k.

Comment: I have some queries regarding your code .singleton list what is it used here and can you explain a bit more about the merge part

Comment: `Collections.singletonList` : Returns an immutable list containing only the specified object. I then create a `new ArrayList` to be able to add elements. Or, if you can use Guava there is `Lists.newArrayList` for that purpose.

Comment: ok  but @OleV.V has done the same thing in different way....can we do the same by using reduce method of java 8 and writing accumulator and combiner

Comment: The merger takes 2 `CustomMessage` objects `m1` and `m2`, copies all  `Aud` objects in the list in `m2` to the one in `m1` and returns `m1`. `m2` is discarded.

Comment: `reduce` on a stream of `CustomMessage` would have to return a single `CustomMessage` not a list. `collect` is the canonical way to return collections as it can return a different type than the type of a stream.

Comment: cant we use reduce accumulator or combiner to create a list of audit for one message and then use it for all messages.Simliar in way map reduce works in hadoop

Comment: @OleV.V. By using    new ArrayList<>(singletonList(new Aud(m.getAudId(), m.getAudmessage())))), are we not creating so many objects every time during iteration and what if there is a case when there are no audits for a message

Comment: That creates a new `ArrayList` for every `Messages`; I believe my approach creates fewer objects. You shouldn’t worry, though, it’s a very small price to pay for clear and readable code. I was assuming a `Messages` always holds one audit. How could it not when it has fields `audId` and `audmessage`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this by *either* grouping *or* reducing. You need both: group first and then reduce. I coded the reduction differently:

```
    List<CustomMessage> list1 = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Messages::getId))
            .values()
            .stream() // stream of List<Messages>
            .map(lm -> {
                List<Aud> la = lm.stream()
                        .map(m -> new Aud(m.getAudId(), m.getAudmessage()))
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());
                Messages m0 = lm.get(0);
                return new CustomMessage(m0.getId(), m0.getMessage(), 
                        m0.getField1(), m0.getField2(), m0.getField3(), la);
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I have introduced a constructor in `Aud` and then read your comment that you are trying to avoid constructors. I will revert to this point in the end. Anyway, you can rewrite the creation of `Aud` objects to be the same way as in your question. And the construction of `CustomMessage` objects too if you like.

Result:

> [1 abc c d f [10 a1, 11 a5], 3 adc s d f [31 a3], 4 aec g d f [40 a4],
>   2 ac d d f [21 a2, 22 a5]]

I grouped messages only by ID since you said their `equals` method uses ID only. You may also group by more fields like in your question. A quick and dirty way wold be

```
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(m -> "" + m.getId() + '-' + m.getMessage() 
                    + '-' + m.getField1() + '-' + m.getField2() + '-' + m.getField3()))
```

Avoiding public constructors and using static methods for object creation doesn’t change a lot. For example if you have

```
public static Aud createAud(int id, String message) {
    return new Aud(id, message);
}
```

(well, this didn’t eliminate the constructor completely, but now you can declare it private; if still not satisfied, you can also rewrite the method into not using a declared constructor). Now in the stream you just need to do:

```
                        .map(m -> Aud.createAud(m.getAudId(), m.getAudmessage()))
```

You can do similarly for `CustomMessage`. In this case your static method may take a `Messages` argument if you like, a bit like Manos Nikolaidis suggested, this could simplify the stream code a bit.

**Edit**: You couldn’t just forget about the three-argument `reduce` method, could you? ;-) It *can* be used. If you want to do that, I suggest you first fit `CustomMessage` with a range of methods for the purpose:

```
private CustomMessage(int id, String msg, 
                      String field1, String field2, String field3, List<Aud> list) {
    this.id = id;
    this.msg = msg;
    this.field1 = field1;
    this.field2 = field2;
    this.field3 = field3;
    this.list = list;
}

public static CustomMessage create(Messages m, List<Aud> la) {
    return new CustomMessage(m.getId(), m.getMessage(), 
                             m.getField1(), m.getField2(), m.getField3(), la);
}

/**
 * @return original with the Aud from m added
 */
public static CustomMessage adopt(CustomMessage original, Messages m) {
    if (original.getId() != m.getId()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("adopt(): incompatible messages, wrong ID");
    }
    Aud newAud = Aud.createAud(m.getAudId(), m.getAudmessage());
    original.addAud(newAud);
    return original;
}

public static CustomMessage merge(CustomMessage cm1, CustomMessage cm2) {
    if (cm1.getId() != cm2.getId()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot merge non-matching custom messages, id "
                + cm1.getId() + " and " + cm2.getId());
    }
    cm1.addAuds(cm2.getList());
    return cm1;
}

private void addAud(Aud aud) {
    list.add(aud);
}

private void addAuds(List<Aud> list) {
    this.list.addAll(list);
}
```

With these in place it’s not so bad:

```
    List<CustomMessage> list2 = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Messages::getId))
            .values()
            .stream()
            .map(lm -> lm.stream()
                        .reduce(CustomMessage.create(lm.get(0), new ArrayList<>()),
                                CustomMessage::adopt, 
                                CustomMessage::merge))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: because i want to have a static method for creation of objects as these are complex objects some are extending them...so i want to write my own static method for object creation.I dont want to introduce constructors.Please advice.Is it possible to write using reduce function with accumulator or combiner.

Comment: Edited, trying to meet your wishes.

Comment: thanks a lot.It works but if possible i want to understand if same code can be written by  List<CustomMessage> list1= list.stream().reduce(new ArrayList<CustomMessage>(),accumulator1, combiner1).

Comment: sure waiting for your reply

Comment: Solved. Took quite some code lines, though. @coder25

Comment: Thks for answer but i am unable to understand what custom message create  method is doing.can u share create method code.

Comment: My `create()` takes ID, message and fields 1 through 3 from the passed `Messages` object and the list of audits from the list passed as second argument. I have included it in the code in the question along with my private constructor. You can of course invent your own variations.

Comment: Just last question regarding the if condition itnis required .will his scenerio come

Comment: You mean the `if` statements in `adopt()` and `merge()`? They are defensive checks. You can remove them. I recommend them since they might help to catch errors.

Comment: Will there be a scenerio  in which this check required  .

Comment: With the code in the answer I’m convinced there will not. You never know when someone on your project calls the same methods from another place.

Comment: Thanks for your time I will try to implement the solution